# Consider $Y = [-1,1]$ as a subspace of $\mathbb{R}$. Which of the sets below are open in $Y$? Which are open in $\mathbb{R}$?

Tags: general-topology

I just learned what a topological space is. Given a set $X$, a topology on $X$ is a collection of subsets of $X$ in which the $\emptyset$ and $X$ are in it, and it's closed under union and finite intersection. An element of a topology is called an open element of that topology. I know how to create topologies for sets like $\{a,b,c\}$ and so on. The problem is that I can't make the connections of what I learned for this exercise. It's asking about the sets:

$$A = \{x: \frac{1}{2}<|x|<1\}$$ 
$$B = \{x: \frac{1}{2}<|x|\le 1\}$$ 
$$C = \{x: \frac{1}{2}\le|x|<1\}$$ 
$$D = \{x: \frac{1}{2}\le|x|\le1\}$$ 
$$E = \{x: 0<|x|<1, \frac{1}{x}\notin \mathbb{Z}_+\}$$

There's something strange for me, I don't know what does it mean to verifiy that an element is open in $Y$ or in $\mathbb{R}$, because I don't know how the topology looks like. For example, given the set $\{a,b,c\}$ and a topology, for example $T = \{\{a\},\{b\}, \{a,b\}, \{a,b,c\}\}$, I can verify for example if $\{c\}$ is open in $T$, which I would say it's not, because it's not in the set $T$. However, what should I do in the sets above? Which is the set $T$ that I'm looking into?

Comment: Given a topological space $X$ and some subset $Y$ of $X$, we say a set $A$ is *open in $Y$* if there is some open set $B\subset X$ such that $A=B\cap Y$.  This defines the subspace topology for a subset of a topological space.

Comment: The standard topology on $\mathbb{R}$ is the one whose base is the open intervals of $\mathbb{R}$, i.e. the topology is all intervals (a,b) where a, b $\in \mathbb{R}$, and unions of such intervals.

Comment: Allow me to amend my comment above by mentioning that intervals of the form (a, $\infty$) and ($\infty$, b) are also in the base.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are given $Y$ is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}$, I would assume you are talking about the [subspace topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subspace_topology) on $Y$. That is, a set $V$ is open in $Y$ if you can write $V = Y \cap U$ for some open set $U$ in $\mathbb{R}$.

Thus the easy ones are

$A = Y \cap \left(\left(-1,-\frac{1}{2}\right)\cup\left(\frac{1}{2},1\right)\right)$ is open

$B = Y \cap \left(\left(-2,-\frac{1}{2}\right)\cup\left(\frac{1}{2},2\right)\right) = \left[-1,-\frac{1}{2}\right)\cup\left(\frac{1}{2},1\right]$ is open

$C$ and $D$ are not open

$E$ is a countable union of open intervals contained in $Y$ and is also open, but this one is a bit more work.

Comment: Isn't set $A$ also composed by $(-1,-\frac{1}{2})$?

Comment: Yes. I forgot the negative half. Will edit.

Comment: why $C$ and $D$ are not open?

Comment: They contain $\frac{1}{2}$ and any open ball around $\frac{1}{2}$ contains elements not in $C$ or $D$.

Comment: why $B$ is the intersection of $Y$ with $(-2,-\frac{1}{2})\cup (\frac{1}{2}, 2)$? Shouldn't it be $-1$ and $1$? I really didn't understand.

Comment: Hmm ok, I did understand now. But how did you interpret the set $E$? I didn't understand where did you took this countable thing